# extends or taking parameter, which approach is better & why

Tags: java

suppose, I have a class Address which has multiple parameters i.e. street number, address line 1, address line 2, country etc. Now, I have a Person class which has multiple parameters i.e. name, email and each person would have an address.

Now, I should take Person class which extends Address class or I should take one address parameter in Person class. Which approach is better & why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a member variable inside Person class. This is called **composition**. **Inheritance** is usually applied where there is similarity between two classes. Mainly from a general class to specialised class. For e.g. Animal class inherited by Dog class.
In other words you can differentiate where to use **composition** vs **inheritance** by simply applying `HAS A` vs `IS A` relationship.

E.g.

- Dog IS A animal.
- Person HAS A address

Comment: Hey Nishant - Thanks for the explanation.

Now, If the situation is - Person class extends Address class or Person class should have one parameter like String address then later (String address) would be a better approach right?

Comment: No, Person and Address class will be separate classes with none inhering the other. Instead, there will be a member variable in Person class of type Address. E.g. `Address address;`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification:)

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer if it clarified your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a member (what you call parameter) of type Address in Person.

Inheritance would be only suitable if you would say "a Person is an Adress with ...". This is not the case here.

In general you should prefer composition to inheritance because your desing will be more flexible.

Comment: Hey Donat - Thanks for the explanation.